# R simplify heatmap to pdf

Tags: graphics, svg, inkscape, r

I want to plot a simplified heatmap that is not so difficult to edit with the scalar vector graphics program I am using (inkscape). The original heatmap as produced below contains lots of rectangles, and I wonder if they could be merged together in the different sectors to simplify the output pdf file:

```
nentries=100000
ci=rainbow(nentries)
set.seed=1
mean=10
## Generate some data (4 factors)
i = data.frame(
  a=round(abs(rnorm(nentries,mean-2))),
  b=round(abs(rnorm(nentries,mean-1))),
  c=round(abs(rnorm(nentries,mean+1))),
  d=round(abs(rnorm(nentries,mean+2)))
  )
minvalue = 10
# Discretise values to 1 or 0
m0 = matrix(as.numeric(i>minvalue),nrow=nrow(i))
# Remove rows with all zeros
m = m0[rowSums(m0)>0,]
# Reorder with 1,1,1,1 on top
ms =m[order(as.vector(m %*% matrix(2^((ncol(m)-1):0),ncol=1)), decreasing=TRUE),]
rowci = rainbow(nrow(ms))
colci = rainbow(ncol(ms))

colnames(ms)=LETTERS[1:4]
limits=c(which(!duplicated(ms)),nrow(ms))
l=length(limits)
toname=round((limits[-l]+ limits[-1])/2)
freq=(limits[-1]-limits[-l])/nrow(ms)

rn=rep("", nrow(ms))
for(i in toname) rn[i]=paste(colnames(ms)[which(ms[i,]==1)],collapse="")
rn[toname]=paste(rn[toname], ": ", sprintf( "%.5f", freq ), "%")

heatmap(ms,
        Rowv=NA,
        labRow=rn,
        keep.dendro = FALSE,
        col=c("black","red"),
        RowSideColors=rowci,
        ColSideColors=colci,
        )

dev.copy2pdf(file="/tmp/file.pdf")
```

Comment: you might try `useRaster=TRUE` in your `heatmap` call, which will get passed to `image` and generate a raster object instead of a bunch of rectangles.  I don't know how Inkscape will handle it, but it does make the PDF 5 times smaller ...

Comment: inkscape on my PC manages to load it with `useRaster=TRUE` but at that point its taken 70% of my RAM. I killed the inkscape that was trying to load the non-useRaster version when it got to 80% of RAM. To be honest, R doesn't handle it too well, if I resize the plot window it all changes, possibly aliasing between data and display pixels. Give up, visualise smarter.

Comment: I tried useRaster=TRUE, but the image only appears white, even before I do dev.copy2pdf. The only bits that are shown are the two rainbow bars on the left and top...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try RSvgDevice? Using it you could save your image as svg file, which is much convenient to Inkscape than pdf

Comment: Thanks. Is there an equivalent of the convenient `dev.copy2pdf` but for `dev.copy2svg`?

Answer (score 1):

I use the `Cairo` package for producing svg. It's incredibly easy. Here is a much simpler plot than the one you have in your example:

```
require(Cairo)
CairoSVG(file = "tmp.svg", width = 6, height = 6)
plot(1:10)
dev.off()
```

Upon opening in Inkscape, you can ungroup the elements and edit as you like.

#### Example (point moved, swirl added):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think we (the internet) are being clear enough on this one.

Let me just start off with a successful export example

```
png("heatmap.png") #Ruby dev's think of this as kind of like opening a `File.open("asdfsd") do |f|` block
heatmap(sample_matrix, Rowv=NA, Colv=NA, col=terrain.colors(256), scale="column", margins=c(5,10))
dev.off()
```

The `dev.off()` bit, in my mind, reminds me of an `end` call to a ruby block or method, in that, the last line of the "nested" or enclosed (between `png()` and `dev.off()`) code's output is what gets dumped into the png file.

For example, if you ran this code:

```
png("heatmap4.png")
heatmap(sample_matrix, Rowv=NA, Colv=NA, col=terrain.colors(32), scale="column", margins=c(5,15))
heatmap(sample_matrix, Rowv=NA, Colv=NA, col=greenred(32), scale="column", margins=c(5,15))
dev.off()
```

it would output the 2nd (greenred color scheme, I just tested it) heatmap to the heatmap4.png file, just like how a ruby method returns its last line by default